# Different backgrounds for different time of day?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing background based on time of day (using javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358155/changing-background-based-on-time-of-day-using-javascript)

I'm looking to create a site where the background rotates a bunch on files for different times of day. Is there any way I can tie maybe a bit of javascript to change the background at certain times based on the either the server or script clock?

I'm looking to have a day/afternoon/evening/night/dawn set of backgrounds that I want to cycle through.

Comment: Someone else has already given a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358155/changing-background-based-on-time-of-day-using-javascript) to this.

Answer (score 3):

Using the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670290/jquery-gettime-function), fetch the local time, and change the CSS of the element, which keeps the background.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this, and then just pass the `i` variable to the element `background-image`:

```
var d = new Date(),
    h = d.getHours(),
    i;

if (h < 6) i = "night.jpg";
else if (h < 9) i = "dawn.jpg";
else if (h < 15) i = "afternoon.jpg";
else if (h < 21) i = "day.jpg";
else i = "night.jpg";

document.body.style.background = "url("+i+")";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/UZG9z/

Comment: shouldn't that be  ='url('+i+')' ?

Comment: @Gerben Yes, and **.style**.background (using.body.background is deprecated)

Comment: There is no need for `h >= 0` since *Date.prototype.getHours* will never return values less than 0.

Comment: @RobG Very true, had a slightly different approach few edits ago, that just got left in there without a reason. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Add this into the head of your HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var styles = ['night', 'dawn', 'afternoon', 'day', 'evening'];
        var currStyle = styles[Math.floor(styles.length * (new Date()).getHours() / 24)];
        document.documentElement.className += ' ' + currStyle;
    }());
</script>
```

Then in your CSS you can use something like this:

```
.night #myelement {
    background-image: url(myImage.jpg);
}
.day body {
    background-color: red;
}
```