# Drop down automatic scroll to selected data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop down list using `<li>` method. I have no display problem selecting the data and highlighting the selected data. By default, the nearest (in future) time will be displayed the input. I want that `onclick` on the input (for the first time), it shows the drop down list, and automatically go to (scroll to) the respective value (the nearest (in future) time).

Just like when you click on the input, then choose the data (eg: 23:00), then close the list. And when you click again on the input, the list will display, and it will automatically scroll at the end to show the previously selected data (23:00).

Hopefully you can understand what i mean.

Here my jsfiddle [drop down list](http://jsfiddle.net/w9j5N/)

Thanks.

Comment: So to clarify; what you want is for it to scroll to the current time automatically?

Comment: I think this can help to solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2906009/1572987

Comment: And maybe look here if you want to find their local time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660927/how-can-i-obtain-the-local-time-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
$('#textin1').click(function() {
        var pos = $('#textin1').offset();
        pos.top += $('#textin1').width();

        $('#dropdown').fadeIn(100);
       $('#dropdown').scrollTop($('#dropdown').find('li:contains("'+$('#textin1').val()+'")').position().top);
        return false;
    });
```

See js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w9j5N/1/

Comment: @user Cache your selectors `var $el = $('#element');`

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eqOtuZUq/1/edit)**

This one will;

- read the current time
- the UL will appear with a nice slide
- the`UL` will scroll to that time-respective `LI` setting it in the view-center
- and the ugly scrollbars will appear only on `UL` hover

Improved jQuery:

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready

  var $dd = $('#dropdown');
  var $t1 = $('#textin1');
  var $currHoursLI = $('li', $dd).eq( new Date().getHours() );
                                 // or use manually  i.e. .eq(23) to test

  $t1.click(function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();      
    var dH = $dd.height();
    var pos = $(this).offset(); 
    pos.top += $(this).width();   
    $currHoursLI.addClass('selected'); 
    $dd.stop().slideDown(200, function(){
       var liPos = $currHoursLI.position().top;
      $(this).animate({scrollTop : liPos-dH+dH/2}, 500);
    });      
  });

  $('li', $dd).click(function() {
    $t1.val($(this).text());
    $('li', $dd).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected').parent($dd).slideUp(200);
  });

  //to hide listing when on click anywhere
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var t = e.target;
    if (!$(t).is($t1) && !$(t).parents().is($t1))$dd.slideUp(200);
  });

});
```

Slightly better CSS:

```
#dropdown {    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid #A4A4A4;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    background:#f9f9f9;
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#dropdown:hover{
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#dropdown li:hover, #dropdown .selected{
    background:#ccc; 
    cursor:pointer; 
}
```